# How to slow down the Timeline key frame duration

Tags: java, javafx

HI is it possible to slow down the Timeline ticks? 
I mean can we manipulate the keyframe duration.

I want to achieve the effect of roulette when it starts to spin quickly and slowing down.

But the keyframe is created once and added to the timeline.

My code looks like this at the moment.

```
button.setOnAction(event -> {

            tick = 0.01;

            roll.setText("0");
            roll.setFont(new Font(72));

            timeline = new Timeline();
            timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

            final KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(tick),
                    e -> {
                        randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 66 + 1);

                        roll.setText(randomNum + "");
                        tick = tick + 0.01;
                        if (tick >= 1.0) timeline.stop();

                    });

            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
            timeline.playFromStart();
        });
```

or should I just do it in the for loop with decreeing thread sleep?
And then observe it and use whenever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a list of `KeyFrame`s, add them all to the timeline, and then just play the timeline once. The following is equivalent to what you tried to implement: note that it will take `10 * 100 * 101 / 2 = 50500` milliseconds (50.5 seconds) to roll the die, which is probably a little too long, so you might want to adjust some of the values in this.

```
Duration nextFrameTime = Duration.millis(10);
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
for (Duration frameTimeIncrement = Duration.millis(10); 
     frameTimeIncrement.lessThan(Duration.seconds(1));
     frameTimeIncrement = frameTimeIncrement.add(Duration.millis(10))) {
    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(nextFrameTime, 
        e -> roll.setText(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 66 + 1) + ""));
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
    nextFrameTime = nextFrameTime.add(frameTimeIncrement);
}
timeline.play();
```

Comment: Thank you, James, Works like a charm.